# HDRI setup without the .hdr or .exr

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

Is there a way to make HDRI, a 360 illumination, without world node ?
Just using lamps. 
I would like to have a darkened area.
Everything needs to be lit but center object should have small color tinted light.

I would like to save that setup and use it in different scene.
Also, could I have some control to overall rotation of the lamps as in mapping node = rot. along z axis?

Comment: Could you maybe explain or illustrate what you're going for a little better? The way I read it you might be better off using regular environment HDRi lighting and then simply blocking the world illumination from your center object via an opaque mesh that is invisible to camera rays (and possibly shadow rays, too) and then set up local lamps behind that "sun screen" But then I might be completely misunderstanding what you're after, which is why I'm not (yet) posting this as an answer...

Comment: @OliverGiesen ,
 
thanks for suggestion. I would like to setup outdoor studio lighting but  dimmed. Only center object gets lit the most. Basically, I would like to setup 360 lighting using only lamps. Also, I would like that this setup could easily be implemented in other scenes and blends.